# Android:'Force Close'error during http post request

Tags: android, http, post, http-post

Initially my activity calls `new DropboxApi(token).execute();` with token.

```
public class DropboxApi extends AsyncTask<Void, Long, Boolean> {
    public String token;
    public DropboxApi(String a) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        token=a;
    }
    String HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM = "HmacSHA1";
    public String Sign(String token)// throws Exception
    {
        String uri = "https://api.dropbox.com/1/account/info";
        //Uri json = GetResponse(uri);
        //return ParseJson<Account>(json);
        uri+="?";
        String queryParams = "oauth_consumer_key=2f2y1dyuqhp58ek&oauth_token="+token+"&oauth_nonce=6880853&oauth_timestamp=";

         java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
         //System.out.println(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));

         queryParams+=(new Timestamp(date.getTime()).toString())+"&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=";

         uri+=queryParams;
         Mac mac=null;
        try {
            mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         Key key=new SecretKeySpec("2f2y1dyuqhp58ek".getBytes(), HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM) ;
         try {
            mac.init(key);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         byte[] rawHmac = mac.doFinal(queryParams.getBytes());
         String result=new String(Base64.encode(rawHmac,Base64.DEFAULT));
         uri+=result;
         return uri;


    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();   
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(Sign(token));
            int k=0;
            k=23;
            HttpResponse response;
            try {
                int j=3;
                j=0;
                response = httpclient.execute(httpPost); // the request executes
                Log.d("HTTP","Executed");
        String  responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(ConnectTimeoutException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //return null;

        return null;
    }


}
```

In debug,Code works fine until it returns uri..which is:

https://api.dropbox.com/1/account/info?oauth_consumer_key=2f2y1dyuqhp58ek&oauth_token=wz27t6thob0fbxl&oauth_nonce=6880853& oauth_timestamp=2012-06-24 23:46:51.734&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=s8zaFHmQJ24BTxTYV4VUSLdV9d8=

This is my first time making an http request..is this code supposed to work?

```
06-24 23:44:47.364: E/AndroidRuntime(11315):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-24 23:44:53.033: I/Process(11315): Sending signal. PID: 11315 SIG: 9
06-24 23:45:43.404: W/ActivityThread(11375): Application cloud.mobile is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
06-24 23:45:43.563: I/System.out(11375): Sending WAIT chunk
06-24 23:45:43.683: I/dalvikvm(11375): Debugger is active
06-24 23:45:43.846: I/System.out(11375): Debugger has connected
06-24 23:45:43.887: I/System.out(11375): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 23:45:44.087: I/System.out(11375): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 23:45:44.338: I/System.out(11375): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 23:45:44.544: I/System.out(11375): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 23:45:44.773: I/System.out(11375): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 23:45:44.983: I/System.out(11375): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 23:45:45.183: I/System.out(11375): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 23:45:45.393: I/System.out(11375): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 23:45:45.594: I/System.out(11375): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 23:45:45.805: I/System.out(11375): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 23:45:46.004: I/System.out(11375): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 23:45:46.214: I/System.out(11375): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 23:45:46.414: I/System.out(11375): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 23:45:46.627: I/System.out(11375): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 23:45:46.833: I/System.out(11375): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 23:45:47.034: I/System.out(11375): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 23:45:47.254: I/System.out(11375): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 23:45:47.466: I/System.out(11375): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 23:45:47.663: I/System.out(11375): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 23:45:47.873: I/System.out(11375): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 23:45:48.073: I/System.out(11375): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 23:45:48.283: I/System.out(11375): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 23:45:48.483: I/System.out(11375): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 23:45:48.684: I/System.out(11375): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 23:45:48.894: I/System.out(11375): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 23:45:49.094: I/System.out(11375): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 23:45:49.295: I/System.out(11375): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 23:45:49.504: I/System.out(11375): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 23:45:49.714: I/System.out(11375): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 23:45:49.915: I/System.out(11375): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 23:45:50.123: I/System.out(11375): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 23:45:50.323: I/System.out(11375): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 23:45:50.524: I/System.out(11375): waiting for debugger to settle...
06-24 23:45:50.754: I/System.out(11375): debugger has settled (1426)
06-24 23:45:53.493: D/dalvikvm(11375): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 721 objects / 53976 bytes in 321ms
06-24 23:48:29.164: D/AndroidRuntime(11375): Shutting down VM
06-24 23:48:29.164: W/dalvikvm(11375): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
06-24 23:48:29.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11375): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-24 23:48:29.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11375): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 122: https://api.dropbox.com/1/account/info?oauth_consumer_key=2f2y1dyuqhp58ek&oauth_token=wz27t6thob0fbxl&oauth_nonce=6880853& oauth_timestamp=2012-06-24 23:46:51.734&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=s8zaFHmQJ24BTxTYV4VUSLdV9d8=
06-24 23:48:29.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11375):    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:970)
06-24 23:48:29.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11375):    at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost.<init>(HttpPost.java:79)
06-24 23:48:29.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11375):    at cloud.mobile.DropboxApi.httpMethod(DropboxApi.java:67)
06-24 23:48:29.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11375):    at cloud.mobile.MCActivity$3.onClick(MCActivity.java:161)
06-24 23:48:29.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11375):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
06-24 23:48:29.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11375):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
06-24 23:48:29.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11375):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-24 23:48:29.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11375):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-24 23:48:29.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11375):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-24 23:48:29.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11375):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-24 23:48:29.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11375):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-24 23:48:29.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11375):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-24 23:48:29.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11375):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-24 23:48:29.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11375):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-24 23:48:29.423: E/AndroidRuntime(11375):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are trying to perform a network access on the UI thread. You should *never* perform potentially expensive operations (network accesses, file I/O, remote database connections, database transactions, etc.) on the this thread, as it might block the UI thread and prevent your layout from inflating/responding to touch events. You need to wrap your HTTP Request in an `AsyncTask` (recommended) or `Thread` instead.

Read my blog post on the subject:

### [Why Ice Cream Sandwich Crashes Your App](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html)

---

Also, there is a space in the url (lol)... that's why you are getting an `IllegalArgumentException` on character 122. Remove the space from `... 6880853& oauth_timestamp=2012 ...`

The stuff I wrote above still applies. Please, please, ***please*** don't perform this task on the UI thread.

Comment: did you fix the space in the url? if so, then i imagine you aren't getting the same error as before. please update ALL of your code so that your post is 100% up to date. that's the only way i can help you out :)

Comment: remember about what i said about the UI thread... don't be like all of the crappy android apps that are already on the Android market :)

Comment: Good Advices like these are pretty hard to find..
That was a good read..
i will be reading your your blog...

Comment: Thanks :). Let me know if you think I should write about something in particular!